# WebStorm Firebase Integration

Tags: firebase, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm pretty new to Firebase, and Web Development in general. Does anyone know how to avoid errors like these in WebStorm?

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Ideally I would like to be able to point Webstorm towards some resource so it recognizes these functions. Everything works and this is technically just an annoyance, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To link `Firebase` as a library in WebStorm's JavaScript project do as follows:

1. Hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`S` to open `Settings` page.
2. Open page `Language & Frameworks` > `JavaScript` > `Libraries`
3. Hit `ADD...` button on right
4. Fill name as `firebase`
5. Hit `+` and `Attach Directories`
6. Find your `node_modules\@firebase` folder inside current project
7. You can OK twice to confirm and close `Settings` page
8. Now your `Firebase` is recognized by WebStorm and all `@types` are defined, and you can `Ctrl`+`Click` any function, and get code completion!

Best regards!

Comment: Man this question is like 3 years old

Comment: But was wiewed 278 times since then... just to help people. Thanks for accept!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `firebase` as a dependency to package.json and then doing `npm install` should do the trick – WebStorm fill index the source files and provide code completion for Firebase APIs.

Alternatively, you can download [firebase-app.js](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-app.js) and [firebase-auth.js](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-auth.js) from the CDN and then configure them as a Library in WebStorm as described in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_js_custom_third_party_library).